# Select node if there periods overlap

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a content type that has a start_date and end_date fields.

I need to make a view with a filter: start_period - end_period

The view should select all nodes where the two periods overlap, for example:

node: 1 jan 2015 - 31 Dec 2015

filter values to select this node could be:
1 oct 2014 - 1 feb 2015
1 oct 2014 - 1 mar 2016
1 apr 2015 - 1 may 2015
1 apr 2015 - 1 mar 2016

Filter values that do not select the node could be:
1 oct 2014 - 1 dec 2014
1 jan 2016 - 1 mar 2016

Is there a module to do that?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try [contextual range filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter) module that lets you define a range filter applies that rule

> Start value <= Filter value >= End value.

For your case you have to define two filters.

for start date with that rule

> filter start date <= node start date >= filter end date.

for end date with that rule

> filter start date <= node end date >= filter start date.